# Is it possible to POST kibana index patterns into the .kibana index of elasticsearch?

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a kibana instance that is brought up using docker and ansible. When this kibana instance is being brought up the Elasticsearch instance it's connected to is already running. I apply some index templates using curl and want to do something similar for index patterns and later on visualizations and dashboards.

I've succeeded in using the kibana API to do this but in my scenario I need this to be done automatically and before the kibana instance is up and running so I get a connection refused since kibana obviously isn't running yet.

Both ES and kibana are running on version 6.2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CURL should work for you:

`curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/.kibana/doc/index-pattern:my-index-pattern-name" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "type" : "index-pattern",
  "index-pattern" : {
    "title": "my-index-pattern-name*",
    "timeFieldName": "execution_time"
  }
}'`